# How do I fix "Error 1001. InstallUtilLib.dll: Unknown Error" when installing proprietary software with Wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine, 19.04, microsoft

I am installing an orthodontic PMS on Ubuntu 19.04.  I can get as far as accepting the EULA and telling the installer to install for either everyone or just myself (roaming vs local), the error pops up either way.  The installer allows me to start the installation, but this pops up every time.

I have installed [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) and the latest version of the [.NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer) from MS. I checked that the DLL is in the directory, and it's there.  I even tried copying/pasting it into the installation folder on the off chance that that would work.

The installation ZIP came with both a .exe and a .msi, and the error pops up with both.

This program (Ortho2 EdgeCloud) is not on Wine's list, so there's limited assistance available on the Wine site.  Am I missing a step?

[image: ErrorDialog]
[image: Files]
[image: DLL]